# Amazon Seller Account and Salesforce Integration

Tags: salesforce, integration, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

Can we integrate amazon seller account (Amazon Marketplace Web Service) from salesforce and handle all the listings and orders .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the Enterprise Edition of Salesforce, then you can write your own Apex code to integrate with the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service](https://developer.amazonservices.com/).
If you don't have Enterprise Edition or don't want to write our own code, then you can try a pre-built app on the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=amazon%20marketplace).